# Google Feeds API setup not working in Chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-api, google-chrome-devtools, google-feed-api

I'm trying to get the Google Feed API to work by simply copy-pasting the example code from Google's tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/feed/v1/devguide

**(!) It works fine in every browser except Chrome.**

I created an HTML file with this code (from Google's "Hello World" tutorial):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://fastpshb.appspot.com/feed/1/fastpshb");
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("feed");
          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(entry.title));
            container.appendChild(div);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="feed"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I load the HTML file, I get this error in the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How are you loading the HTML file? Which browser are you using to view it? It works perfectly for me in Firefox, IE and Chrome on Win 7.

Comment: I'm using the latest version Chrome

Comment: Update: it works perfectly fine on Firefox, but not in Chrome... How can that be?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. https://disconnect.me/ was running on Chrome and stopped the script from working.